# WordPress Rest API Image Upload CORS Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, reactjs, axios, wordpress-rest-api

I'm having a (seemingly simple) problem uploading images to Wordpress through it's REST API. Here's the situation right now:

- I'm currently developing locally on my machine so I'm running Wordpress with MAMP.
- I'm using React on the front end of my application and using Wordpress REST API as the backend; so I'm running a headless CMS app right now.
- Using Postman, I am able to upload an image onto Wordpress. I can go to the Wordpress admin panel and see the image actually there in the dashboard. I've got authentication down too, I'm logged in both on my app and have the JWT token being passed in with the headers with Postman.

**The Problem**: I'm using Axios to make the same Post request as I am from Postman but I get some sort of CORS error and I'm not sure how to safely enable CORS on the Wordpress Backend.

Here's the exact error from my browser's console:

> *Failed to load http://localhost:8888/wp-json/wp/v2/media: Request header field cache-control is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.*

**My AJAX Call (this is in React and using Axios)**

```js
onFileChange(event) {
    let files = event.target.files || event.dataTransfer.files;
    if (!files.length) {
        console.log('no files');
    } else {
      axios.post('http://localhost:8888/wp-json/wp/v2/media', files, {
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'image/png',
          'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=testImageNum2.png',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
          'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        }
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <h2>Upload A File Here:</h2>
        <input id="file_selector" type="file" name="file" onChange={this.onFileChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

There doesn't seem to be too much information on this topic with the WP REST API at the moment. If anyone could help shed some light on this topic, I would be extremely grateful!

Answer (score 0):

The error states that your client (axios) is sending a request which has a "cache-control" header (`'cache-control': 'no-cache',`) but cache-control isn't in Apache's `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` list of allowed headers. Add "cache-control" to that list or disable it in axios.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I disabled both content-disposition and cache-control because they both threw the errors. But now I'm getting a 403 (Forbidden) error now.

I think I have to try adding "cache-control" and "content-disposition" to Apache's Access-Control-Allow-Headers list. Will try to figure that out on my own but if you have any recommended resources I'd be really grateful :)